# Angular 2 - Cannot access component members/methods from SignalR scope

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to use signalr (externally loaded scripts) with angular 2 components but facing a wired issue. My functions are getting called in typescript with correct information that I am passing from WebAPI but inside those typescript functions I cannot use any of my declared properties or functions.

From my WebAPI, I am notifying the clients like

```
IHubContext hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CarBidHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.NotifyManager_BidPlaced(message);
```

This initiates a call in my angular component where I have defined it like

```
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var moment: any;
var hub = jQuery.connection.carBidHub;  //declaring hub
@Component({
    selector: 'live-auction',
    templateUrl: '/auctions/live/live-auction.html'
})
export class LiveAuctionComponent
{
    ...
    constructor(private notificationService: NotificationsService)
    {
    }
    ...

    private startHub(): void {
            jQuery.connection.hub.logging = false;

            hub.client.NotifyManager_BidPlaced = function (message:string) {
                //this message is printed on all connected clients
                console.log(message);   

                //but this line below throws an error on all members I am trying to access with "this."
                this.notificationService.success('Information', message);   
            }

            //this.notificationService is available here

            //Start the hub
            jQuery.connection.hub.start();
    }
}
```

I have tried to call

```
//call start hub method 
this.startHub();
```

from ngAfterViewInit, OnInit and constructor of the component but none worked.

I can guess the issue that signalr's receiver is defined inside a typescript function so it might not have the right context when called externally.

> Is there a way I could access declared members from this
>   NotifyManager_BidPlaced function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of examples out there with the same issue. Rule of thumb, never use the `function` keyword inside your classes. This will replace the `this` context with that of the current function scope. Always use the `() => {}` notation:

```
private startHub(): void {
    jQuery.connection.hub.logging = false;

    hub.client.NotifyManager_BidPlaced = (message:string) => { //here
      this.notificationService.success('Information', message);   
    };

    jQuery.connection.hub.start();
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I never knew it changes the scope by using the function keyword, thank you :)